# Convert JSON string to Avro GenericRecord in Java (the generated Schema is through the same Json string)

Tags: json, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm getting JSON string as an input,
I converted the Json string to avro schema using this

> Schema schema = JsonUtil.inferSchema(JsonUtil.parse(jsonString),
>   "schema");

I have the avro schema which I can register in schema registry.

I need a genric record out of the same string, as the JSON data holds the values as well.

Comment: Where are you getting this JsonUtil class? Please show it

Comment: @cricket_007 I got that from the Kitesdk.data

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you are trying to programmatically re-create the `kafka-avro-console-producer` which takes the schema as a CLI argument, then JSON matching the schema as user input.

You can find a corresponding jsonToAvro method there

https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/formatter/AvroMessageReader.java

Which just uses Avro's included JSONDecoder

```
  private Object jsonToAvro(String jsonString, Schema schema) {
    try {
      DatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<Object>(schema);
      Object object = reader.read(null, decoderFactory.jsonDecoder(schema, jsonString));

      if (schema.getType().equals(Schema.Type.STRING)) {
        object = ((Utf8) object).toString();
      }
      return object;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new SerializationException(
          String.format("Error deserializing json %s to Avro of schema %s", jsonString, schema), e);
    } catch (AvroRuntimeException e) {
      throw new SerializationException(
          String.format("Error deserializing json %s to Avro of schema %s", jsonString, schema), e);
    }
  }
```

This returns a String or a GenericRecord instance

Comment: Thanks for the link, the code has changed a bit. The method is `readFrom` which converts JSON string to Avro Record.

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
tech.allegro.schema.json2avro.converter
```

Now I need to pass schema and the json data(as bytes) and this would give me the record.

```
JsonAvroConverter avroConverter = new JsonAvroConverter();

GenericData.Record record =
avroConverter.convertToGenericDataRecord(json.getBytes(), avroSchema);
```

Comment: AFAICT, that's just a wrapper around the code I copied. No need to add another dependency outside Avro